# WCF Service (non-web) Configuration Warning

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

Visual Studio keeps throwing me 2 warnings:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     WCF configuration validation warning: The 'name' attribute is invalid - The value 'MyServiceLibrary.MyService' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceNameType'.  MyServiceLibrary    C:\MyDrive\Flavor\Net\1.0\App\MyServiceLibrary\App.config   10  
Warning     WCF configuration validation warning: The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'MyServiceLibrary.IMyService' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceContractType'. MyServiceLibrary    C:\MyDrive\Flavor\Net\1.0\App\MyServiceLibrary\App.config   11
```

Here is part of the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MyIpc.IpcAppToService">
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/MyIpcAppToService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyAppToIPCEndpointBinding" name="MyIpc_IIpcAppToService" contract="MyIpc.IIpcAppToService"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/MyService/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        ...
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is the service file:

```
namespace MyServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is the interface file:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace MyServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/GetVersionInfo")]
        [OperationContract]
        string GetVersionInfo();
    }
}
```

Here is my understanding (app.config):

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="namespace" name="<namespace>.<service name>">

<endpoint address="..." ... contract="<namespace>.<interface name>"/>
```

In my case the service name does not reside in a sub-directory, so:

```
namespace=MyServiceLibrary
service name=MyService    (file is MyService.cs)
interface=IMyService      (file is IMyService.cs)
```

That makes:

```
<service ... name="MyServiceLibrary.MyService">
```

and

```
 <endpoint ... contract="MyServiceLibrary.IMyService"/>
```

I already know as a fact that `contract` is `namespace.interface`.

Had I placed the service and interface files in a sub-directory, Communication, which I did not, but say that I did, then

```
<service ... name="MyServiceLibrary.Communication.MyService">
<endpoint ... contract="MyServiceLibrary.Communication.IMyService"/>
```

Where `MyServiceLibrary.Communication` is the namespace.

Annoyingly, I still get the warnings:

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
 Warning        WCF configuration validation warning: The 'name' attribute is invalid - The value 'MyServiceLibrary.MyService' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceNameType'.  MyServiceLibrary    C:\MyDrive\Flavor\Net\1.0\App\MyServiceLibrary\App.config   10  
 Warning        WCF configuration validation warning: The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'MyServiceLibrary.IMyService' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceContractType'. MyServiceLibrary    C:\MyDrive\Flavor\Net\1.0\App\MyServiceLibrary\App.config   11
```

There are several SO topics, usually on web services, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732696/cannot-set-service-name-attribute-in-web-config-for-wcf-web-service) is representative and says what I just did.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's aggravating that VisualStudio even *makes* an app.config for .dll projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing is that, because you said this is a **non-web** configuration, that means you're *self-hosted*...meaning there's an small shim of an .exe project that starts (windows service or auto-activated or something). It's that .exe project's **app.config** that needs all this config info.

The reason I'm suggesting this is because it keeps saying `MyServiceLibrary.MyService` and `MyServiceLibrary.IMyService` meaning the edits your doing aren't being reflected when your app starts...meaning (probably) you're editing the app.config in the library project (the .dll). That doesn't work.

(Notice the warning in the comment:

> *<!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
>     app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->*

They didn't have that warning back when I first stumbled across this particular issue. But, I understand about comments in config files...they're just so much noise that they disappear entirely ;-)

Once you're editing the right **.config**, you'll start getting better warnings, and by-and-large you appear to be on the right track.

So, if you've got some .exe project that starts the service, it has to create an instance of your service.

```
svc = new ServiceHost( typeof( ServiceNamespace.ServiceClass ) );
svc.Open();
```

...where `svc` is a persistent object of some kind (depending on the host). If it's a Windows Service, you're WCF service goes into instance data of your overridden `ServiceBase` class...and the foregoing code goes into the `OnStart` method. If it's a console app, you make a `Main` method that creates the object and then just sleeps in a loop (open wcf service doesn't listen in the startup thread).

Comment: Nice answer good sir.  I formatted your answer a bit, feel free to roll-back if you don't like :) )

Comment: @MickyD Looks fine. Thanks ;-)